# PHP: How to unset all variables from included file?

Tags: php, include, unset

PHP: How to unset all variables from included file?

Comment: have you looked into namespacing?  I think that might make more sense.

Comment: @circusdei The problem is that the library is creating the globals, I suppose namespacing your variables should avoid that problems

Comment: If 2 libraries are conflicting with each other in the global namespace, there's not much you can do besides modifying them. But kgb's answer is the best way to see which variables are causing problems.

Comment: `curl -s http://punbb.informer.com/download/punbb-1.4.2.tar.gz | tar -xOz | grep -aF 'global $' | sed 's/\tglobal //;s/, /\n/g' | tr -d '$;\t' | sort -u` OH MY GOD SO MANY GLOBALS

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php), but using [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) makes much more sence.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
foreach($GLOBALS as $key => $val) {
    unset($GLOBALS[$key]);
}
```

I would never do this though. Look into namespacing, like some of the commenters said.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use global variables for two reasons

- Spaghetti code
- Name clashes

I can't address the spaghetti code part of it, but I can suggest you move all your global variables into its own class to avoid the name clashes

Instead of setting global variables, you could set them as static properties of a single global object

```
class Globals {
  public static global1 = 0;
  public static global2 = 2;
}
```

And use them in your code like

```
Globals::global1 = 5;
```

This avoids name clashes, but I still avoid it and try to implement my code without resorting to globals.

Answer (score -2):

Use unset();

ex. unset($_POST); unset($_GET); unset($data);

Comment: The OP doesn't know which variables to call `unset` on, they're put there by a library